# SonarOube: StartSonar.bat gives error:java.lang.IllegalStateException: Webapp did not start

Tags: web-applications, sonarqube, illegalstateexception, sonarqube-ops, java

```
--> Wrapper Started as Console
Launching a JVM...
2016.09.12 20:04:22 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatContexts] Webapp directory: D:\sonarqube-5.6\sonarqube-5.6\web
2016.09.12 20:04:22 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-9000"]
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2016.09.12 20:04:22 INFO  web[o.a.t.u.n.NioSelectorPool] Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
2016.09.12 20:04:22 INFO  app[o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory D:\sonarqube-5.6\sonarqube-5.6\temp
2016.09.12 20:04:22 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[es]: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\sonarqube-5.6\sonarqube-5.6\temp -javaagent:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer D:\sonarqube-5.6\sonarqube-5.6\temp\sq-process2331191922867561813properties
2016.09.12 20:04:23 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerImpl] SonarQube Server / 5.6 / 074f3d1169f9688d15af4aff67e7e672cbeed782
2016.09.12 20:04:23 INFO  web[o.sonar.db.Database] Create JDBC data source for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/eisonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance
2016.09.12 20:04:23 INFO   es[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint]  Starting es
2016.09.12 20:04:23 INFO   es[o.s.s.EsSettings]  Elasticsearch listening on 127.0.0.1:9001
2016.09.12 20:04:23 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1473690862599] version[1.7.5], pid[5104], build[00f95f4/2016-02-02T09:55:30Z]
2016.09.12 20:04:23 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1473690862599] initializing ...
2016.09.12 20:04:23 INFO   es[o.e.plugins]  [sonar-1473690862599] loaded [], sites []
2016.09.12 20:04:24 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener
org.sonar.api.utils.MessageException: Current version is too old. Please upgrade to Long Term Support version firstly.
2016.09.12 20:04:24 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.StandardContext] One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
2016.09.12 20:04:24 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.StandardContext] Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
2016.09.12 20:04:24 WARN  web[o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
 com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:43)
2016.09.12 20:04:24 WARN  web[o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
 java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
2016.09.12 20:04:24 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-9000"]
2016.09.12 20:04:24 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is started
2016.09.12 20:04:24 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] HTTP connector enabled on port 9000
2016.09.12 20:04:24 WARN  web[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Fail to start web
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Webapp did not start
    at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.isUp(EmbeddedTomcat.java:84) ~[sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.isUp(WebServer.java:47) [sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:105) ~[sonar-process-5.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.main(WebServer.java:68) [sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
2016.09.12 20:04:24 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-9000"]
2016.09.12 20:04:24 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.env]  [sonar-1473690862599] using [1] data paths, mounts [[Project_Source (D:)]], net usable_space [76.9gb], net total_space [99.9gb], types [NTFS]
2016.09.12 20:04:25 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-9000"]
2016.09.12 20:04:25 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-9000"]
2016.09.12 20:04:25 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is stopped
2016.09.12 20:04:25 WARN   es[o.e.bootstrap]  JNA not found. native methods will be disabled.
2016.09.12 20:04:25 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is stopping
2016.09.12 20:04:25 INFO   es[o.s.p.StopWatcher]  Stopping process
2016.09.12 20:04:26 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1473690862599] initialized
2016.09.12 20:04:26 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1473690862599] starting ...
2016.09.12 20:04:26 INFO   es[o.s.p.StopWatcher]  Stopping process
2016.09.12 20:04:26 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1473690854594] stopping ...
2016.09.12 20:04:26 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1473690854594] stopped
2016.09.12 20:04:26 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1473690854594] closing ...
2016.09.12 20:04:26 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1473690854594] closed
2016.09.12 20:04:26 INFO   es[o.e.transport]  [sonar-1473690862599] bound_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9001]}, publish_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9001]}
2016.09.12 20:04:26 INFO   es[o.e.discovery]  [sonar-1473690862599] sonarqube/o61SSzjpRiyDs0g8T3cORw
2016.09.12 20:04:26 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is stopped
<-- Wrapper Stopped
2016.09.12 20:04:29 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.service]  [sonar-1473690862599] new_master [sonar-1473690862599][o61SSzjpRiyDs0g8T3cORw][SonarQube][inet[/127.0.0.1:9001]]{rack_id=sonar-1473690862599}, reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
2016.09.12 20:04:29 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1473690862599] started
2016.09.12 20:04:29 INFO   es[o.e.gateway]  [sonar-1473690862599] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
2016.09.12 20:04:29 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is up
2016.09.12 20:04:29 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.management.enabled=false -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\sonarqube-5.6\sonarqube-5.6\temp -javaagent:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/server/*;D:\sonarqube-5.6\sonarqube-5.6\lib\jdbc\mysql\mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer D:\sonarqube-5.6\sonarqube-5.6\temp\sq-process8086380433005857585properties
2016.09.12 20:04:29 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[web] is stopping
2016.09.12 20:04:30 INFO  web[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting web
2016.09.12 20:04:30 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatContexts] Webapp directory: D:\sonarqube-5.6\sonarqube-5.6\web
2016.09.12 20:04:30 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-9000"]
2016.09.12 20:04:30 INFO  web[o.a.t.u.n.NioSelectorPool] Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
2016.09.12 20:04:31 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerImpl] SonarQube Server / 5.6 / 074f3d1169f9688d15af4aff67e7e672cbeed782
2016.09.12 20:04:31 INFO  web[o.sonar.db.Database] Create JDBC data source for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/eisonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance
2016.09.12 20:04:32 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener
org.sonar.api.utils.MessageException: Current version is too old. Please upgrade to Long Term Support version firstly.
2016.09.12 20:04:32 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.StandardContext] One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
2016.09.12 20:04:32 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.StandardContext] Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
2016.09.12 20:04:32 WARN  web[o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
 com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:43)
2016.09.12 20:04:32 WARN  web[o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
 java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
2016.09.12 20:04:32 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-9000"]
2016.09.12 20:04:32 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is started
2016.09.12 20:04:32 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] HTTP connector enabled on port 9000
2016.09.12 20:04:32 WARN  web[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Fail to start web
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Webapp did not start
    at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.isUp(EmbeddedTomcat.java:84) ~[sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.isUp(WebServer.java:47) [sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:105) ~[sonar-process-5.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.main(WebServer.java:68) [sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
2016.09.12 20:04:32 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-9000"]
2016.09.12 20:04:33 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-9000"]
2016.09.12 20:04:33 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-9000"]
2016.09.12 20:04:33 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is stopped
2016.09.12 20:04:33 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[web] is stopped
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

The Sonarqube version I am using is 5.6 and MySQL version 5.7.
It seems to be some port issues because the sonar 5.x versions use 2 ports by default, port 9000 and 9001.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You shouldn't request others to do this "ASAP".  You will get less likely a chance of an answer and it does annoy users.  You should be patient and appreciate people's efforts to take their free time to assist you when they do not get paid.

Answer (score 3):

You missed the ERROR log "Current version is too old. Please upgrade to Long Term Support version firstly.". I suppose that you attempt to upgrade an old version 3.x or < 4.5.x of SonarQube. You should first upgrade to 4.5.x then jump to 5.6.

Comment: A minor though, Simon: the English in that error message is a bit stilted. Could it be modified to read `Please upgrade to Long Term Support version first`?